# How to print a Question paper with Two column layout A4 page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

`ol li` Print with **Two Column layout**.  `ol` contains more than **80** `li`s. 
I used bootstrap 3. If `li` Reach End of page its goes to next column. if Two column reach `ol li` start two next page
**For Example**,

```
I Need This:
 Column 1 (col-md-6)            Column 2 (col-md-6)
 List 1                         List 6       
 ---                            ---  
 List 2                         List 7  
 ---                            ---
 List 3                         List 8 
 ---                            ---
 List 4                         List 9 (Long Question. This is End Column 2)
 ---                            ---  
 List 5(This is End Column 1)
 ---
 <!----------- THIS IS END OF PAGE 1 --------------->
<!----------- PAGE 2 START --------------->
 Column 3 (col-md-6) 
 List 10
 --- 
 List 11 
 ---  
 List 12
 ---
 List 13(This is End Column 3)
<!----------- THIS IS END OF PAGE 2 --------------->
```

### [**Sample Demo**](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/YpyVxx)

*in this demo:* 21 and 22 List items are place on 2nd page.. but this actually placed on first page 2nd column top. also the List 44 is placed on third column top. but now its wrongly placed on second column.

[image]

NOTE: I Prepare Question paper. So i need Two column for Print A4 Sheet. I need some suggestion .. **Is it possible used with Jquery and CSS ?**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of bootstrap grid use css3 `coulmn` property, like

```
ol {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
ol {
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 40px;
}
```

Here `column-count: 2;` will create two grid that devides all `li` into `2` and `column-gap: 40px;` is the space between 2 grids.

Comment: Yes, when `li` count is `even` , but if you have 9 `li`s then first column will have 5 and the second column will have/contain remaining 4 `li`s

Comment: What actually you want to be happened?

Comment: [Demo](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/YpyVxx).. in this demo 21 and 22 Question place on 2nd page.. but this is actually place on **top on first page 2nd column**